# Java downcasting dilemma

Tags: java

please have a look at this code here.

```
class Vehicle {
    public void printSound() {
        System.out.print("vehicle");
    }
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
    public void printSound() {
        System.out.print("car");
    }
}

class Bike extends Vehicle{ // also tried to extend Car
    public void printSound() {
        System.out.print("bike");
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle v = new Car();
        Bike b = (Bike)v;
        v.printSound();
        b.printSound();

        Object myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
        for (String s : (String[])myObj) System.out.print(s + ".");


    }
}
```

Executing this code will give `ClassCastException` saying `inheritance.Car cannot be cast to inheritance.Bike`.

Now look at the line `Object myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};`. This line is same as `Vehicle v = new Car();` right? In both lines we are assigning sub class object to super class reference variable. But downcasting `String[]myObj` is allowed but `(Bike)v` is not. As mentioned in the comment I also tried to extend Car using bike. According to some discussion here, Bike is not a car because it is extending vehicle. If I extend Car by a Bike, then it means Bike is a type of Car, still the exception remains.

Please help me understand what is going on around here.

P.s - please don't take the whole convert car to bike, bike to car literally ;)

Comment: You're trying to turn a `Car` into a `Bike`. But `Car` doesn't inherit from `Bike`. It's the other way around.

Comment: Unfortunately THIS language is not as realistic and logical sounding as English language. So yes, I am trying to turn a car into a bike

Comment: Or rather, most programming languages... :)

Comment: please see the edit. As Cratylus had mentioned that car and bike are unrelated. I extended bike from a vehicle. I still get the same exception

Comment: With your edit. Conceptually speaking, a `Car` is not a `Bike` so it makes sense that you *can't* convert them into each other.

Comment: but then what was the problem in earlier case. When Bike extended Car. Then a bike was a type of car. Still it gave exception!

Comment: In that first version, a `Bike` is a `Car`. But a `Car` is not necessarily a `Bike`. Therefore you can't cast down unless it really *is* a bike.

Comment: I am sorry if I am sounding repetitive or stubborn, but by what you just said, does that mean that string is type of object and an object is a type of string? As your reasoning was that `Bike` is a `Car` BUT `Car` is not neccessarily a `Bike`. Please bear with me I am totally new in java

Comment: No. Because the `Object` really is a `String` in that example.

Comment: I had this question on a interview. I failed it! Oh gosh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the code provided differs from the code in your example in a basic sentence:

```
//you're declaring a Object class variable
Object myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};
//you're declaring a Car class instance, not a Vehicle
Vehicle v = new Car();
```

They're not the same. In the first example, you're using the parent class to save the value, in the second you're using a child class and assigning a parent value, but the object will be a child, not the parent.

Let's see the classes composition for further explanation:

```
Object
- String[]
- Vehicle
  - Car
  - Bike
```

As you can see, every `String[]` will be a `Object`, now every `Car` will be a `Vehicle`, but a `Car` is not a `Bike`. Explaining it with code

```
Vehicle v = new Car();
//v contains an instance of Car
Car c = v;
//a Car is not a Bike, this line will throw an error
Bike b = c;
//v2 contains an instance of Vehicle
Vehicle v2 = new Vehicle();
//a Car is a Vehicle
Car c2 = v2;
//a Bike is a Vehicle
Bike b2 = v2;
```

Comment: no actually according to code it is something like `Vehicle -> Car` and `Vehicle -> Bike`. You mentioned it to be like `Car -> Vehicle`. Which is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between the two is example is that `Object myObj = new String[]{"one", "two", "three"};` here `myObj` will reference an array of String, and since the referenced value is indeed a array of Strings you may cast it to one. 
In the other example `Bike b = (Bike)v;` the referenced value of `b` will be to a `Car`. And since `Car` is not a complete `Bike`. The bike may implement more then the car, things the car doesn't know about. And hence you cannot cast a `Car` to be a `Bike`

Answer (score 2):

The two are not the same: `(String[])myObj` is allowed because `myObj` is a `String[]` instance. But `(Bike)v` is not allowed because `v` is not an instance of a `Bike` or any of its superclasses (it is a `Car` instance).